# How to convert JSON to CSV

Tags: json, csv

I have a JSON of an array of key - value pairs and I want to convert it to a CSV file of two columns. All resources I tried online converted it to 2 rows of many columns, but I want two columns of multiple rows.

Example, what I have:

```
{
    "abnormal": "Abnormal",
    "action_bar": "Action bar",
    "active": "Active"
}
```

What I want:

| abnormal  | Abnormal  |

| action_bar| Action bar|

| active    | Active    |

Comment: What you show under "What I want" is not CSV (CSV stands for comma separated values).  Do you want CSV or what you showed in the question?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thank you, A CSV that can be opened in an excel, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which programming language are you using?

If it's python, I recommend [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

If it's javascript then here:

```js
var data = {
    "abnormal": "Abnormal",
    "action_bar": "Action bar",
    "active": "Active"
}

var csv = "";
var replacer = []
for (const key in data) {
    csv += key + "," + data[key] + "\r\n";
}
console.log(csv)

var exportedFilenmae = 'export.csv';

var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
} else {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
        // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```